# Tree using ul li and javascript without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

I try to make a simple tree using javascript without plugin in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Undy/)

Here is my html

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li>First Child
        <ul>
            <li>First Child
                <ul>
                    <li>First Child</li>
                    <li>Second Child</li>
                    <li>Third Child</li>
                    <li>Fourth Child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Second Child</li>
            <li>Third Child</li>
            <li>Fourth Child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second Child</li>
    <li>Third Child</li>
    <li>Fourth Child</li>
</ul>
```

and my js

```
$( "li" ).on( "click", function() {
    if ($(this).children('ul').css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).children('ul').css("display", "");
    } else {
        //alert( $( this ).text() );
        $(this).children('ul').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

but it only working with first level. How to do that thanks.

Comment: Refer This Link This may help you http://jenkov.com/books/jquery/tree.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event bubbling is happening out there. use `e.stopPropagation()` to block that. And by the way you don't need to change/check the display property to make any element visible/hidden, just use 
    `.toggle()`.

Try,

```
$("li").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();       
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Undy/2/)